# Rewriting jQuery $.xjax loadmore function as XMLHttpRequest JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, xmlhttprequest

I've run into issues trying to write a XMLHttpRequest loadmore function over $.ajax and unsure what i'm missing.

Below is my function which is based on a working $.ajax version I have used before. With jQuery version I use a data object, but I can't get this to work it XMLHttpRequest. I've tried including it with FormData, but I don't think it's the right way to go.

Data Object example from jQuery version which adds WP specific data relating to post type, action to link with PHP function etc:

```js
data = {
          action: "loadmore",
          query: WP.posts, // that's how we get params from wp_localize_script() function
          page: WP.current_page
        };
```

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const el = document.getElementById("loadmore");

  if (el) {
    el.addEventListener("click", e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      el.value = this.value;

      xhr.onload = function() {
        const button = this;

        if (xhr.status === 200) {
          document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;

          if (data) {
            WP.current_page++;
            if (WP.current_page == WP.max_page) button.remove(); // if last page, remove the button
          } else {
            button.remove(); // if no data, remove the button as well
          }
        } else {
          console.log(xhr.status);
          console.log(xhr.response);
          console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
      };

      xhr.open("POST", WP.ajax, true);

      // const formData = new FormData(el);

      const data = new FormData();
      data.append("action", "loadmore");
      data.append("query", WP.posts);
      data.append("page", WP.current_page);

      xhr.send(data); 
    });
  }
```

Here is an example of working jQuery function. Innocence I'm wanting the same results but with XMLHttpRequest... Any help/direction would be appreciated :)

```js
jQuery(function($) {

    $("#loadmore").click(function() {
      var button = $(this),
        data = {
          action: "loadmore",
          query: WP.posts,
          page: WP.current_page
        };

      $.ajax({
        url: WP.ajaxurl, 
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
          button.text("Loading..."); 
        },
        success: function(data) {
          if (data) {
            button
              .text("More posts")
              .prev()
              .before(data); 
            WP.current_page++;

            if (WP.current_page == WP.max_page) button.remove(); 
          } else {
            button.remove();
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

So I worked out the solution. If anyone is interested here it is:

As you can't use a data object like you can for $.ajax, appending to formData achieves the same results, then add data const in send.

```js
const data = new FormData();
      data.append("action", "loadmore");
      data.append("query", WP.posts);
      data.append("page", WP.current_page);

xhr.send(data);
```

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
const el = document.getElementById("loadmore");


    el.addEventListener("click", e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      el.value = this.value;

      const data = new FormData();
      data.append("action", "loadmore");
      data.append("query", WP.posts);
      data.append("page", WP.current_page);

      xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
          document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
          console.log(xhr.responseText);
          WP.current_page++;
        } else {
          console.log(xhr.status);
          console.log(xhr.response);
          console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
      };

      xhr.open("POST", WP.ajax, true);

      xhr.send(data);
    });
```

If there is a better way of doing this please let me know.